# Apostrophe 3 CMS not showing the modal when clicking admin bar

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

I have a CMS that created with Apostrophe 3 and it's already working fine previously.
But I have issue appeared in a few days ago that not showing any modal when I click on the admin bar to see the list and adding new record for my CMS (sometimes only showing the loading overlay, but the modal still doesn't showed up). I see that Apostrophe 3 already a hotfix for this kinda issue (i using chrome too) but it still doesn't work even I already update the Apostrophe package, I figuring out that if you make the connection slower (i did this with change my network to fast/slow 3g in chrome dev tools) it will works and the modal will show up.

Here's the gif image for this issue:
https://ibb.co/5FvRkqt

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I realize you posted this question a long time ago, but if you are still experiencing the issue, please share any messages that appear in the browser console. Otherwise it is difficult to guess at the issue. (Right-click, Inspect, then click on the "Console" tab)

Comment: Also share anything that appears in the terminal window where Apostrophe is running, or if this is in production, whatever output was produced in the console logs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some close tag is missing in the layout.html and it's causing the modal not to show up, after reverting my changes in that file and making it as the default one then everything seems fine